# mockit.internal.MissingInvocation Exception - using Spring , Jmockit

Tags: spring, junit4, jmockit

I am using JMockit with Spring and trying to verify some method from my service layer but i couldn't make it successful.

Find the below sample code

UserRepositoryImpl.java

```
package com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.repository.impl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.User;
import com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.repository.UserRepository;

@Repository("userRepository")
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{



    /**
     * Not yet implemented. 
     * 
     * @param User
     * @return
     */
    public User getLoggedInUser() {

        User user =  new User();
        user.setUsername("admin");
        user.setPassword("test123");
        return user;
    }

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.service.impl;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.User;
import com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.repository.UserRepository;
import com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.service.UserService;


    @Service("userService")
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{


        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;


        public User getLoggedInUser() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            User user = userRepository.getLoggedInUser();
            System.out.println("user service " + user.getUsername());
            return user;
        }

    }
```

And my Test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/ApplicationContext.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class JMockitVerificationTest {

    @Tested
    private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();

    @Injectable
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Test
    public void testUserServiceUserList() {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                userRepository.getLoggedInUser();
                result = new User("guest", "test123");
            }
        };

        userService.getLoggedInUser();

        new Verifications() {

            {
                userRepository.getLoggedInUser();
            }
        };

    }
}
```

It's running success if i remove the verification block and getting expected result.

Trying to verify my method whether it is get invoked in service or not but getting below exception.

```
mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing invocation of:
com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.repository.UserRepository#getLoggedInUser()
   on mock instance: com.test.jmockit.JMockitsample.repository.$Impl_UserRepository@425407
        at com.test.jmockit.JMockitVerificationTest$2.<init>(JMockitVerificationTest.java:45)
        at com.test.jmockit.JMockitVerificationTest.testUserServiceUserList(JMockitVerificationTest.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: Missing invocation
        ... 24 more
```

Don't know where i have done the mistake to make it success, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the test still fail if the custom Spring runner is not used (ie, if you remove the `@RunWith` line)?

Comment: yes, it is still failing with same exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem. I copied the code from the question, but it runs fine (no exception), with or without `@RunWith`.

Comment: Thanks - Rogerio, but in my case its completely failing don't know why. i just found the alternative when i use NonStrictExpectations instead of Expectations it works as expected.